# Printing beamer in pdf

Tags: printing

I have `beamer` presentation in PDF (I don't have the LaTeX document). Is there a way to print it without pauses so I don't get duplicate information?

Comment: There is a class option `handout`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: The O.P. does not have the LaTeX source ... (the `handout` option was my first idea too, but then I reread the question)

Comment: But without the LaTeX source… I don't think there's much to do with LaTeX, am I right?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I think you can only print the document selectively, by deciding manually which pages should be printed.

Answer (score 4):

Create a LaTeX document with package `pdfpages`. Then the PDF file can be included with `\includepdf[pages={...}]{slides.pdf}`. Specify the pages with option `pages`, which you want to print. The package has other options, e.g. to print two slides on one page, ...

Example:

```
\def\SlidesFile{slides.pdf}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[
  pages={1, 3, 6},
  fitpaper,
]{\SlidesFile}
\end{document}
```